Contour Integral with Branch Cut of $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}}\,dz$
A physicist here, so my Complex Analysis is a bit rusty, but given $|a|,|b|<1$ are inside the contour and $|c|,|d|>1$ outside, can we apply residue theorem here for
$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}} \, dz$$
If so what kind of pole do we have? an if not, how would one even tackle this problem?
Similar problems of this include the "residue" at infinity but it's something that I could not expand (Expansion at $\infty$ gives powers of $\frac{1}{z^2}$)
Context: I've never really understood applying the residue theorem with branch cuts, and the examples that I've found usually have something that can be rewritten to have a pole, for example, $$\frac{1}{z^2-1}= \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{z^2}}}.$$ But here if you pull out the $z$, you get $\frac{1}{z^2}$ for which I am awestruck.

Why should this question be closed ?

The poles you have to consider are those inside the integration contour, i.e., $a$ and $b$. Besides, what is the branch-cut you are mentionning ? Another question : is your integral connected with Schwarz-Christoffel transformations ?

@JeanMarie Oh! I never thought to look at it that way, but initially no. This is actually just a separate question on these contour integrals. The branch-cut I was talking about was that at $a$ and $b$ we have a so called "branch cut singularity". My understanding is that anything with $\frac{1}{z}$ is a (simple) pole and thus we can find the residue, but what about this one?

The integrand has no poles, but rather branch points (and branch cuts). The corresponding the Riemann surface
$$w^2=(z-a)(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)$$
is a torus and the contour $|z| = 1$ becomes a cycle. In particular, OP's integral is essentially an elliptic integral.
Now, to compute the integral, we first substitute $z = a + \frac{p}{x + q}$. Then with a suitable choice of $p$ and $q$, we can reduce the differential form $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{w}$ into the form
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{w} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{4x^3 - g_2 x - g_3}} $$
for some constants $g_2$ and $g_3$ determined by $a, b, c, d$. (Of course, the branch must be chosen carefully so that the sign of the both sides match.) So, the question reduces to integrating the differential form $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y}$, where
$$ y^2 = 4x^3 - g_2 x - g_3. $$
Now, we substitute $x = \wp(\zeta)$, where $\wp$ is the Weierstrass elliptic function associated with some period lattice $\Lambda$. This substitution is an isomorphism between the above elliptic curve and the $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. Moreover,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{y} = \mathrm{d}\zeta. $$
Finally, if $\gamma$ denotes the image of the cycle $|z| = 1$ under the substitution $z \mapsto x \mapsto \zeta$, it follows that
$$ \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{w} = \int_{\gamma} \mathrm{d}\zeta. $$
Since $\gamma$ is a cycle, it therefore follows that the integral corresponds to a period of $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$.

Example. Consider the Riemann surface
$$ w^2 = z(2z-1)(z - 2i)(z + 2i). $$
Let $\sqrt{z} = \exp(\frac{1}{2}\log z)$ be the principal square root so that $\arg z \in (-\pi, \pi]$, and consider the differential form
$$ \eta = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z}\sqrt{2z-1}\sqrt{z-2i}\sqrt{z+2i}}. $$
We will sketch how to compute $\int_{|z|=1} \eta$ using the theory of elliptic curves.
In doing so, we note that $\eta$ is holomorphic near $|z| = 1$, hence the integral is well-defined. Indeed, the figure below visualizes $\eta$ together with the resulting branch cutssrc), which clearly avoids the cycle $|z| = 1$:

Now substitute $z = \frac{3}{2-3 x}$ into the integral $\int_{|z|=1} \eta$. Then the cycle $|z|=1$ is mapped to a clockwise-oriented circle of radius $1$ centered at $\frac{2}{3}$, and the transformed differential along with its branch cuts looks likesrc):

Shifting the branch cuts appropriate while not crossing the cycle, we may replace $\eta$ bysrc)
$$ \eta = \frac{\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{-(3 x+4)} \sqrt{-\left(36 x^2-48 x+25\right)}} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

This is a differential form on the elliptic curve
$$ y^2 = 4 x^3-\frac{13}{3} x + \frac{100}{27} $$
Now following the recipe in this article, we can find $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, the periods of the associated Weierstrass elliptic functions, as
\begin{align*}
\omega_1
&= \frac{\pi}{\operatorname{agm}\left((-1)^{1/4},\sqrt{2+\frac{i}{2}}\right)}
\approx 2.43618 - 1.09813 i, \\
\omega_2
&= \frac{\pi}{\operatorname{agm}\left((-1)^{-1/4},\sqrt{2-\frac{i}{2}}\right)} 
\approx 2.43618 + 1.09813 i.
\end{align*}
Let $E = \mathbb{C} / \Lambda$ be the associated elliptic curve where $\Lambda = \omega_1 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \omega_2 \mathbb{Z}$. Then the cycle, mapped into $E$, looks like:src)

From this, we quickly realize that $\eta$ winds $E$ in the direction of $\omega_2 - \omega_1$ once, and therefore
$$ \int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{z}\sqrt{2z-1}\sqrt{z-2i}\sqrt{z+2i}} = \omega_2 - \omega_1 \approx 2.19626 i. $$
This matches the value directly obtained via numerical integration.

[+1] Thanks for this very deep and inspiring answer ! I imagine that the color code in the plots is related to the phase ? May I ask you which software you have used for these plots ?

@JeanMarie, Thanks! Indeed the color code is based on the phase of the value. I used Mathematica 14 for drawing the images.

You will hopefully be interested by my answer here which explains why (by separating $\sqrt{(z-a)(z-b)}$ and $\sqrt{(z-c)(z-d)}$) 2 "forbidden" line segments are used in the answer by Sangchul Lee.

@SangchulLee Wow, very thoughtful and insightful answer, thank you! I do two questions:

@SangchulLee


For $|z|=1$, don't you have $1=|z|= \frac{|3|}{|2-3x|}|= \frac{3}{3}\frac{|1|}{|\frac{2}{3}-x|}$ is a circle of radius $1$ centered around $\frac{2}{3}$ right?


Could you elaborate on how you got the $y^2$ in that closed form? It seems that $$dy= \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^3-\frac{13}{3}x+\frac{100}{27}}} (12 x^2-\frac{13}{3})dx$$ which clearly is not
$$\eta=\frac{\sqrt{27}}{\sqrt{-(3x+4)}\sqrt{-36x^2+48x-25}}$$ right? or am I missing something


Are there analytic expressions for $p,q$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$?


Many Thanks!

@JeanMarie Thank you for the link! It was a good read and helped me understand branch cuts better!

@SangchulLee Apologies for the multiple mention, but lastly, How did see "quickly" that $\eta$ winds around $E$ in the direction of $\omega_1-\omega_2$? and How did you plot the curve onto E? I've never encountered elliptical curves hence the questions. Thank you!

@deedeefive (1) Indeed, the circle should be $|x-\frac{2}{3}|=1$. I originally worked with different equations, which was later replaced by an easier one. I forgot to change that part :s (2) We have to transform the differential form $\eta$ itself, rather than the equation. (Most of all, what we care here is the integral!) You have to make the following change: $$\eta=\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{f(z)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}(\frac{3}{2-3x})}{f(\frac{3}{2-3x})}.$$ Then the transformed differential can be re-interpreted as a form on another rational curve, given by the equation in my answer.

(3) We can of course derive a formula for $p$ and $q$. They are rational functions of $a, b, c, d$. (4) Your question is valid, since it is not easy to grasp how the trajectory looks like on $E$. In fact, I used Mathematica 14 to plot the curve, and only after that I was able to deduce that it winds $E$ in the direction of $\omega_2-\omega_1$ (which, in the figure, is the upward vertical direction). And to help you understand this, note that the actual $E$ is obtained as a quotient $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$. In particular, each pair of the two opposite sides of the rhombus are identified.

Now, bisect the rhombus in the figure along its vertical axis, creating left and right triangular halves. Then, stack these halves vertically. This rearrangement still gives a valid representation of $E$, and you can now clearly see that the trajectory forms a curve tracing $E$ "vertically upward".

@SangchulLee Fantastic! Alot of things are making sense now, I thought that the orthogonal $x-y$ axes were $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ instead of the rhombus. Last question, how did you "plot" this curve in Mathematica 14? I ask because I intend to find $p,q$ in terms of our rational functions but wonder how I'd find the "direction" and the number of times it winds in that direction in that case as well. Many thanks for the answer!
